# Как в Google Colab скопировать ячейку в буфер обмена, а затем вставить её в нужном месте программы (блокнота)?

Tags: python

Как в Google Colab скопировать ячейку в буфер обмена, а затем вставить её в нужном месте программы (блокнота)?

1. Элемент списка.

Comment: Не очень понятно, но я обычно копирую всё, что в ячейке выделив через `Ctrl+A` и скопировав через `Ctrl+Ins`, а потом вставляю `Shift+Ins`

Comment: Можно подробнее, какую ячейку копировать, с чем работаешь ?